# According to Catholicism, where will our resurrected bodies be after the 'final judgment'?

Tags: catholicism, resurrection, resurrection-body, second-coming

According to official Catholic teaching, the righteous will be judged after death and then go to either heaven (or purgatory) or hell.

However, there will then by a 'final judgment', at which point everyone will be reincarnated ('resurrected') in glorified bodies.

Where will these glorified bodies be (will they all be on planet Earth), according to Catholicism?

Comment: Notes until I have time to write a formal answer: 1) There are 2 major views: transformation or destruction+recreation; 2) scope is whole universe, not just planet Earth, note the language "New *Heaven* and Earth", with "Heaven" here means sky+stars, not God's dwelling proper (where His throne is); 3) need to research which option the Catholic church chooses (or leaves open); 4) some clues: [CCC 1042-1050](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p123a12.htm#VI), [Article XII of the 1566 Catechism](http://www.saintsbooks.net/books/The%20Roman%20Catechism.pdf)

Comment: Question is if there would be enough space here on earth for everybody if all the dead people came back. One estimation is that there are 15 dead people on every living one. How accurate that figure is can be debated, but it ought to be a relatively high number.

Answer (score 1):

According to Catholicism, God will create a "new earth" where our new bodies will live. Whether this means that the earth is literally destroyed and remade, or that the physical world will be perfected on the last day, that is up to individual speculation. But our bodies will need to be somewhere in space and time, and the tradition of the Church is that a new earth will be that somewhere.